# how to check if a php file is obfuscated?

Tags: php, obfuscation

is there any way we can check if a php file has been obfuscated, using php? I was thinking regex maybe (for instance ioncube's encoded file contains a very long alphabet string, etc.

Answer (score 3):

One idea is to check for whitespace. The first thing that an obfuscator will do is to remove extra whitespace. Another thing you can look for is the number of characters per line, as obfuscators will put all the code into few (one?) lines.

Comment: Well, not necessarily.  Code can have plenty of whitespace and be obfuscated.  Though, this is a good "quick and easy" way to check.

Answer (score 1):

Often, obsfuscators initialize very large arrays to translate variables into less meaningful names (eg. see [obsfucator article](http://internetmarketingcoding.com/php-obfuscation-example)

One technique may be to search for these super-large arrays, close to the top of the class/file etc. You may be able to hook xdebug up to examine/look for these. The whole thing of course depends on the obsfuscation technique used. Check the source code, there may be patterns they've used that you can search on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use token_get_all() to parse the file - then compute some statistics. For example check for number of function calls(in calse obfuscator uses some eval() string and nothing else) and calculate average function length - for obfuscators it will usually be about 3-5 chars, for normal PHP code it should be much bigger. You can also use dictionary lookup for function/variable names, check for comments etc. I think if you know all obfuscator formats that you want to detect - it will be easy.